# Holding out on object creation

Tags: c#, oop, class, object, constructor

Is there ever a case where holding the necessary data to create an object and only creating it when is absolutely necessary, is better/more efficient than holding the object itself?

A trivial example:

```
class Bar
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

class Foo
{
    Bar bar;
    readonly string barData;

    public Foo(string barData)
    {
        this.barData = barData;
    }

    public void MaybeCreate(bool create)
    {
        if (create)
        {
            bar = new Bar { Data = barData };
        }
    }

    public Bar Bar { get { return bar; } }
}
```

Comment: Nothing is ever created until runtime. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes sense if the object performs some complex operation on construction, such as allocate system resources.

You have [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx) to help you delay an object's instantiation. Among other things, it has thread safety built in, if you need it.

Comment: +1 for Lazy<T>, that definitely makes sense in this situation

Answer (score 3):

In general, no. (If I understand your question correct).

Allocations/constructions are cheap in terms of performance. Unless you are doing something crazy, construct your objects when it feels natural for the design - don't optimize prematurely.

Comment: Agree. Do not do too much work in a constructor. It is much better to redesign the class which has a havy construtor. Following link is  a google's recomentation about that. Very good explanation.

http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/

Comment: @gmamaladze -not sure how "heavy constructors" relate to my question. This question is more about lazy loading, than how to create flexible constructors... in fact, you'll notice the Foo constructor follows the principles outlined in your link.

Answer (score 1):

Yes if creating the object means populating it, and to populate it you need to do a slow operation.

For example,

```
List<int> ll = returnDataFromDBVeryVerySlowly();
```

or

```
Lazy<List<int>> ll = new Lazy<List<int>>(() =>
{
    return returnDataFromDBVeryVerySlowly();
});
```

In first example `returnDataFromDBVeryVerySlowly` will be called always, even if you don't need it. In the second one it will be called only if it's necessary. This is quite common, for example, in ASP.NET where you want to have "ready" many "standard" datasets, but you don't want them to be populated unless they are needed and you want to put them as members of your Page, so that multiple methods can access them (otherwhise a method could call directly `returnDataFromDBVeryVerySlowly`)